# Help with using "gnome-web-photo" with "at" to get screenshot of website at specific time

Tags: gnome, screenshot, elementary

I want to get a screenshot of a website at a specific time. 
I managed to understand "gnome-web-photo" and it works great standalone but I can't get it to work with "at" so that it triggers at the right time.

Here's what I tried:

```
echo "gnome-web-photo --delay=3 https://example.com output.png" | at 01:11am
```

this it what it returns upon hitting enter:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 34 at Fri Sep  8 01:11:00 2017
```

however, the screenshot never actually appears anywhere (no network activity either). 
I tried googling my problem but it seems like my command should - in theory - work.

Let me know if you need any additional information.

I'm running elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-web-photo` is a graphical application, but `at` does not provide a graphical environment. If you're sure you'll be logged in when this runs, you can cheat, and let `at` use your logged-in GUI.

```
echo "env DISPLAY=:0 $(type -p gnome-web-photo) --delay=3 https://example.com output.png" | at 01:11am
```

Comment: Thank you **very** much!

You don't know how much easier you've just made my life. Had to grab around 40 screenshots per day at very specific times. Now I don't need to sit in front of my machine anymore, waiting to hit enter..